Starting Weblogic 12c 12.1.2 Server fails when started through Eclipse
WebLogic is configured in Eclipse Photon as describe in many tutorials on the internet.
After configuring the WebLogic 12c 12.1.2, the server is added successfully, domain and all other things are setup correctly
But after server is started, the console starts to show logs. In the console log the Weblogic server is started successfully
When the weblogic server is started the eclipse tries to connect with deployment manager,
The following message shows in the ErrorLog view
Server watcher[Oracle WebLogic Server 12c (12.1.2):running WebLogic detected, validating...

and then it fails with following message is shown in ErrorLog View
oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic Error Thu May 02 11:25:52 GST 2024 **Cannot establish connection to deployment manager.Anonymous attempt to get to a JNDI resource To avoid security lockout, Server watcher will NOT attempt to reconnect the server. If you change username/password, please restart Eclipse. **

the eclipse shows the server is not started.
The weblogic server is running in the background and can be connected through localhost:7001
But the eclipse is unable to connect to running Weblogic instance.


If the WebLogic server is started successfully then eclipse should be able to successfully connect to the running instance but it fails with the message
Cannot establish connection to deployment manager. Anonymous attempt to get to a JNDI resource

Eclipse Photon is more than five years and 23 releases behind. Can your issue be reproduced with the current Eclipse version (2024-03)?

It is what is provided by company I am working for. Cannot install new software or any thing else.
I am stuck here, please help if you could
